# Regarding the definition of S-flows over a category (given a monoid S)

Tags: ct.category-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

(This question was originally directed to Simone Virili, referring to the answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/103840/2926, but could also be addressed to the greater community.)

I was wondering if you have any references for the definition you gave in this post: [Is there a categorical treatment of dynamical systems?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103837/is-there-a-categorical-treatment-of-dynamical-systems/103840#103840?newreg=5a4f596a5df344efad81b6f42355ae6e)

I'm looking for a standard categorical treatment of discrete dynamical systems. I know you can give an abstract definition in terms of actions and groupoids but I like yours because it somehow preserves the 'feeling' of a DDS and I need that.

Thanks.

Comment: Who is 'you' in the post?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You is Simone Virili

Comment: Of possible interest: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/8/tr8.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry not to have seen this question until now. I do not have any standard reference for this point of view on dynamical systems.

On the other hand, what you can say is that the category of $\Gamma$-flows, say with  $\Gamma$ a monoid (but you can allow more general things), on a category $\mathcal C$, is exactly the category of functors $Func(\Gamma, \mathcal C)$, where $\Gamma$ is considered as a category with one object.

So, even if the "dynamical" point of view is usually not present, most standard books in category theory study this kind of functor categories.